# Extrapolate table with data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to achieve the following:

In my SQL Server database I currently have this table (4 rows to show the records).

I would like to extrapolate the M_ID column, which currently only has 4 distinct values to  distinct 200 values.

The values in the other columns can be the same or be a random value/data

What is the best way to approach this?

T1

```
P_M                  L_U                   U_D_T_P         M_ID
4/9/2020 9:00:00 PM  4/9/2020 9:00:00 PM     2              105
5/9/2020 9:00:00 PM  4/9/2020 9:00:00 PM     2              111
7/9/2020 9:00:00 PM  4/9/2020 9:00:00 PM     2              112
5/9/2020 9:00:00 PM  4/9/2020 9:00:00 PM     2              113
```

Comment: Please provide some desired results to make it clear what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generate a random value, using:

```
rand(checksum(newid()))
```

This can then be incorporated in your logic.  In an `update`:

```
update t
    set m_id = floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 200) + 1;
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. But i would like to insert new rows instead of update the current rows